# How To use auth in laravel 9 Nwidart module?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, backend

I am working on an laravel 9 application. It is developed using https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules modular approach.

I am developing an Agent module in which, any individual can register and login and go to their agent panel also.

Now the **Problem is that i can't to able to perform login/registration because i can't able to define guards in module as it doesn't have any auth file**

Now how can i use independent login/register for this module?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define your guard in the main Laravel application (root) and then use it in the module. it is not a good idea to define guard in the modules

Comment: But, this will destroy the modular architecture?

Comment: no, it doesn`t. Laravel module authentication belongs to the framework. you could define guard in your Module provider or publishes some configs to rewrite the auth.php file when your going to config your module